# Kill 2 other process with .sh Script

Tags: command-line, sound, bash, scripts, java

I have a radio.sh file. I start it from Java with:

```
Process ls=null;
BufferedReader input=null;
String line=null; 
try {
    ls= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "/home/djeki22/Dokumente/radio.sh"});
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ls.getInputStream()));

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();  
        System.exit(1);
      }
```

in the radio.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

rtl_fm -f 103.78M:103.82M:25K -M wbfm -s 159K -r 48K -l 2 -E deemp -F 9 - | aplay -r 48k -f S16_LE
```

I would like to kill this process because I want to change the frequency. I'd like to run a new script `radio1.sh` with the same script, but with other frequency.

I can kill `rtl_fm` and `aplay` with `killall rtl_fm` and `killall aplay`, but `rtl_fm` isn't 100% killed. But I cannot hear anything. If I start java and start this `radio.sh`, I cannot hear anything. It's not working.

If I start `radio.sh` in a terminal, it tells me that it cant open the device. I think the device is in use.

How can I kill this process with a script?

Comment: Is the process definitely killed?  Try "ps -ef | grep rtl_f[m]" and see if anything is listed.  If it is, then yes, the process was not killed.  If it is not, then process was indeed killed, but there is a device driver problem leaving the rtl device inaccessable.  I have seen this happen before, although on other platforms.  My only resolution then was to unplug the RTL dongle and plug it back in again.

Comment: Ty for this Command. I can see the rtl_fm with the -f ... options. If i use the Terminal with the radio.sh script, then i can stop this with strg+c. Then i can start another script. This works, but how i use the strg+c in scripts? Maybe its a result for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to have the process (*rtl_fm*) write it's own PID to a PID file, then use the contents of that file to kill the process.

However, since *rtl_fm* does not have a way to write it's PID to a file, we can use a workaround.

```
#!/bin/bash
RTL_PID=`ps -e | grep rtl_f[m] | awk '{print $1}'`
kill ${RTL_PID}
```

First, we set a variable **RTL_PID** with the processes PID.  We get this by listing all processes, looking for *rtl_fm*.  The `[m]` is a trick that keeps `grep rtl_fm` from showing up in the list of processes.  Finally, take the line output and get the first field from it, which is the PID.

Note that this will send a **TERM** signal to the process.  If that doesn't work and you need to send a **KILL**, add a `-9`, e.g. `kill -9 ${RTL_PID}`.